# How to plot split violinplot or group boxplot with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

My data format is like this:

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| method | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3 | Feature4 | Feature5 | Feature6 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A      | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| B      | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A      | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    | value    |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to plot violinplot like this:

[image]

Where the X-axis is the features and Y-axis is the whole column value, and hue to method. So how to plot with seaborn?
I do read the example code, which seems like I have to reconstruct my data?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test without the data, but this should work.

First, transform your data to [tidy form](http://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html)

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['method'])
# method | variable | value
#   A    | Feature1 |  ...  
#   A    | Feature2 |  ...
```

Then, use the standard seaborn API

```
sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', hue='method', data=df)
```